# HTML 5 Label Tag Need to Be closed?

Tags: html, label

Does the `<label/>` tag need to be closed in html5 doctype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<label>` tags are inline elements, so it should be OK to leave off, as it'll get closed automatically at the end of the block-level element it's contained inside of.

Comment: I changed the font to "em" and noticed that the font was getting smaller on the unclosed labels.

Comment: Without seeing a test page or sample code, it's hard to understand what you're talking about, let alone what the issue is. Ultimately, you should be doing what works. I personally close all tags, even if the closing tag is optional.

Comment: I agree I normally close most tags in html5 except <li>. This is for a mobile site so we are squeezing the markup as much as possible. Here is an example:
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title> 
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
   label{
    font-size:1.4em;
   }
  </style>
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <form>
   <label>Test Title 1
   <input type="text"/>
   
   <label>Test Title 2
   <input type="text"/>
   
   <label>Test Title 3
   <input type="text"/>
  </form>

 </body> 
 
</html>

Comment: While you're squeezing markup, take away the `type="text/css"`. Your problem from that code is clearer - you've got multiple `<label>` open tags within the same block-level element, so you're getting labels within labels. You need to close them, and you need to probably worry less about a few extra bytes of HTML text content. Images are the real spot to optimize for mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Not according to [W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/nu). None of these are valid HTML5:

```
<p><label>e-mail</p>
<label/>
```

The LABEL element need a closing tag. The content inside of the element can be blank, but it needs a closinng tag.

Thinking about it, there should not be any case where a label is voided (`<label/>`) since the semantic value of the element is to assist when filling forms.

Answer (score 1):

As odd as it may sound, it's often worth testing something like this in Internet Explorer. IE is less forgiving than other browsers when it comes to valid HTML and if there's an issue, it will be very noticeable.

HTML tags that are 'empty', i.e. don't contain any content, e.g. the `source` element, tend to be self closing. Other HTML elements that must exist within others, e.g. the `li` element as it needs to be within a `ul` or `ol` element, can also remain so. Following this (admittedly made-up) rule, the `label` element should be closed by the author.

Answer (score -1):

**No. I don't believe so. For questions like this I would suggest Googling it, and bringing problems you can't find an answer to here.**
**EDIT:** Yes. It would be valid.

Comment: Did you check to see if there is an answer in Google for this question? I didn't find anything conclusive.

Comment: Yeah I tried google didn't fine anything conclusive either. I know Paul Irish has discussed tags that you don't have to close in the HTML5 spec but I have yet to find a definitive list.

Comment: I think this is a pretty striahgtforward question, though, since label  is meant to define a 'label', and you cannot define such things without giving it an end-tag, to show the parser to stop creating the label tag. Also, I'd suggest choosing a response as the specified answer :p